# C# Call EXE Method on WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net

it's possible to call method desktop application from webapi ?
I need because I'm developing restful where some dll only run for desktop app.

Thank's

Comment: If your API is RESTful, it cannot "call" anything. It's usually the other way around.

Comment: it's mean I must develop desktop application too ? or can call from webapplication ?

Comment: A desktop application requires someone to be signed on. A web service usually runs in a hosted service context (e.g. IIS) which does not require anyone to be signed on.  It's a very different context. So it is likely you will have some trouble with this.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757126/calling-an-asp-net-console-application-from-my-asp-net-mvc-web-application